# How to split string in multiple column in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to split a value which is in hive column into multiple columns.Please see the pattern below.

```
"[{\"A\":\"1009972\",\"B\":\"003900006647XXVVVVV\"},{\"A\":\"10099725647\",\"B\":\"00390000000000djhdhfga\"}]"
```

I need values like below.

```
A           B
1009972     0039000002FGDkQAAX
10099725647 0039000002FGDkQAAXZZXXCCVVBBN
```

I am able to get the values using stbstr() function in hive .But as we can see the values are dynamic and can be multiple due to which it is failing.How to get values in hive.Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use split function and use explode with the array. i found [This](http://bigdataprogrammers.com/split-one-column-into-multiple-columns-in-hive/) one useful